# Qt converting string to int in base 16 but remain the value of base 16

Tags: c++, qt

This have been troubled me for days and I really have no clue so to trouble Y'all.

I have an input in `Qt` to get any number from the user input.

After the user input the number, I get the number and convert it into hexadecimal (base 16) after I convert it, if the hexadecimal is more than 1 bytes, I will split it into 1 bytes size. I have done all the conversion and splitting.

Now my problem is , after I convert and split, the hexadecimal stays in the data type of QString, but in order to sent inside the QBtyeArray, I need convert back to int.

Can you guys tell me is there any convenient way to convert QString back to the int? I have tried a lot of ways but all of the conversion give me the value of base 10, I want the value to be in base 16 but in int.

Example : The user input 10800 (base 10) in the lineEdit , I retrieve the 10800 from lineEdit and after that I convert it to a base 16, so the hexadecimal of 10800 is 2A30 , after I do the conversion , the value 2A30 is in string , may I know how to convert the type into int but the value still stays as 2A30 but not convert back to 10800 (base 10).

The closest answer I get is through this method

```
unsigned int value = QString("0x2A").toUInt(&ok, 16);

int abcde = sprintf(abc, "%x", value);

qDebug()<<QString::number(value);

QByteArray test_a = abc;
```

but either it returns me QByteArray or char, I want it in int, because I need to specify each bytes I send in writeDatagram() functions like this.

```
 QByteArray datagram(4, '\x000');
    datagram[0] = 0x02;
    datagram[1] = 0x10;
    datagram[2] = 0x00;
    datagram[3] = 0x00;
```

Please tell me if my question is not clear enough. I'm using `Qt 5.2.1`

Thanks !!!

Comment: Your question presumes a solution, but doesn't explain what problem you're solving. Please add a paragraph at the beginning that provides at least 2 or 3 examples of sought **input** to the conversion (i.e. what string did the user enter), and the **output** you expect (i.e. the contents of a `QByteArray`).

Comment: @KubaOber I already added a new example , the input expected from the user is int in  base 10 , after that I need to convert into base 16 , but after I convert the type become QString , so I want to convert it back to int but the value stays what I convert. Is that clear ? If not please tell me again. I will try to explain more clear.

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking for. 10800 and 0x2a30 are the same number when stored in an int. Decimal and Hexadecimal are different ways of visualising that same value.

Comment: Sorry for that , I know is the same value , but when I send through QByteArray , the byteArray only accept int , so I need to convert the data type from String to Integer..

I got specify what I need to send in datagram below. I need to specify each byte what to send. So I have to split and convert it to int and place into the datagram[] byte array.

Comment: Please **show exactly what bytes will be in the byte array!!!!**. We're guessing that they bytes you want are `0x2a` and `0x30`, but in what order and are we guessing right? You're writing a **specification** for your conversion: so write a spec. A spec must provide some examples. The input is a `QString`, the output is a `QByteArray`. Show some pairs `{string, array}` to demonstrate what input-output pairs you'd consider correct. Most of the text in the question is irrelevant. For example, you show `\x02\x10\x00\x00` in the datagram: why?! Use examples that help your spec!

Comment: okay..
1. Input is QString
2. I convert into hexadecimal , means what number input in the QString I will convert it in Hex format.
3. Then I split into 1 byte size for the number I convert.
4. After I split , I wish to send as a QByteArray
5. For example the input is 10800 , then I convert it into 2A30 (hex) then my QByteArray will send 0x2A and 0x30.
6. Ignore the datagram I put that is the other conversion that I done.
7. This is what I can explain , I don't know what more to explain.

Comment: so if the input is 10800 , my output on datagram will be 0x2A and 0x30 ...

Is this clear enough ?

Comment: The part about "conversion into hexadecimal" is irrelevant, since it's an implementation detail that is unnecessary. You don't need to convert into base 16 because your real base is 256, so going via base 16 is... I don't even know where it came from. You want to send integers base 256, just say so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you do the conversion etc.? I presume that you want to send an arbitrarily long integers in, effectively, base 256, i.e. one byte and at a time, instead of, say one decimal digit at a time. I also assume you want to represent them big endian, i.e. the most significant base-256 digit comes first. Say if you had to send 12384928, it'd be sent as bytes 188, 250, 160 (0xbc, 0xfa, 0xa0).

That's pretty easy to do:

```
QByteArray numberToBytes(const QString &number) {
  QByteArray result;
  bool ok = false;
  auto value = number.toLongLong(&ok);
  if (ok) {
    int n = sizeof(value);
    while (value && n--) {
      result.append(quint8(value & 0xFF));
      value = value >> 8;
    }
    std::reverse(result.begin(), result.end());
  }
  return result;
}

QString bytesToNumber(const QByteArray &bytes) {
  qlonglong value = 0;
  for (auto b : bytes)
    value = (value << 8) | quint8(b);
  return QString::number(value);
}

void test() {
  Q_ASSERT(sizeof(qlonglong) == 8);
  Q_ASSERT(numberToBytes("256") == QByteArray::fromRawData("\x01\x00", 2));
  Q_ASSERT(numberToBytes("2134789") == QByteArray::fromRawData("\x20\x93 \x05", 3));
  Q_ASSERT(numberToBytes("-58931") == QByteArray::fromRawData("\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\xFF\x19\xCD");
}
```

You might also consider numbers too long to fit in 8 bytes. Those require a slightly more involved radix change operation - after all, you don't really want to be doing repetitive long divisions. See [this page](http://www.numberworld.org/y-cruncher/internals/radix-conversion.html) for details.

But it really looks as if you want to simply send strings in datagrams. If you wish to append a checksum (here: CCITT CRC-16) to the data, that's not hard either, because Qt does it for us:

```
QByteArray serialize(const QString &str, bool withCRC = false) {
  QByteArray result;
  QDataStream ds(&result, QIODevice::WriteOnly);
  ds << str;
  if (withCRC) ds << qChecksum(result.constData(), result.size());
  return result;
}

QString deserialize(const QByteArray &packet, bool withCRC = false) {
  QString result;
  QDataStream ds(packet);
  ds >> result;
  if (withCRC) {
    quint16 crc;
    ds >> crc;
    crc ^= qChecksum(packet.data(), packet.size() - 2);
    if (crc) return {};
  }
  return result;
}
```

The format of the datagram is as follows: length of the string (4 bytes), followed by each character in the string (2 bytes each - it's a `QChar`). The optional CRC is another 2 bytes. That's all there's to that.

If the string has only ASCII characters, then sending the UTF-8 representation will take half the space if the string is long:

```
QByteArray serialize(const QString &str, bool withCRC = false) {
  QByteArray result;
  QDataStream ds(&result, QIODevice::WriteOnly);
  ds << str.toUtf8();
  if (withCRC) ds << qChecksum(result.constData(), result.size());
  return result;
}

QString deserialize(const QByteArray &packet, bool withCRC = false) {
  QByteArray result;
  QDataStream ds(packet);
  ds >> result;
  if (withCRC) {
    quint16 crc;
    ds >> crc;
    crc ^= qChecksum(result.constData(), result.size());
    if (crc) return {};
  }
  return QString::fromUtf8(result);
}
```

Perhaps you tried to make the string smaller by knowing ahead of time that it is a number, and thus representing it optimally. How long do you expect those strings to be, and what is your limit on the datagram size?

Comment: I want to send it through QUDPSocket , sorry I didn't mention that. So I have to send in QByteArray and I need to be sure about the size of the data I send , for example 10800 is 5 bytes in string , but only 2 bytes in Hexadecimal (0x2A and 0x30) so in total I only need to send 2 bytes through UDP socket. The UDP socket I already done and I have a function call writeDatagram() to handle this. So now my concern is how can I convert the 0x2A and 0x30 into int , now my 2A and 30 is in string.

Comment: @Reggie You need to do nothing. Use `QDataStream` and it will serialize and deserialize strings for you. Why are you complicating this so badly?

Comment: I just new to Qt , I never use Qt before. And this have been stuck me for days. I tried the QDataStream can it be send through QByteArray ?? and the size will remain 2 bytes also ?

Comment: I tried the QDataStream before, but it seems like not working in my case..or maybe I've done it the wrong way. I try again and see.

Comment: The size doesn't need to remain 2 bytes at all. It's a detail that doesn't matter. You push `QString` on one end, and you receive `QString` on another end. And that's all you care for. The `QString` doesn't even need to carry a number. It can be anything. You could copy-paste a book by Shakespeare into the line input and it'd come out the same on the other end.

Comment: In my projects it's matter, because I will have a checksum to check the byte I send and in the other end, I need to received the correct byte for checking. So this is the things I matter now. It have to be 2 bytes long and I have no other choice.

Comment: Thanks for you help , I will try it one by one to see which 1 is working and can be implemented into my project.

Comment: So you want to send some CRC with your packet? That's still trivial - see edit.

Comment: Okay , Now I resolved my problem !!! Thanks for that, you did help me a lot..appreciate !!!